# Fact that perl ternary operator faster than if else

Tags: perl, optimization

Is perl ternary operator faster than if else, if so by how many time, how to prove it?

Comment: Normally you'd benchmark things like this, and [Benchmark](https://perldoc.perl.org/Benchmark) module is good for it.  However, I doubt that one can detect the difference for this, given how subtle it is and how much overhead there is in setting up any kind of timing/benchmarking.

Comment: If this difference is what's slow about you program, you're is better shape than almost every other programmer in the world. :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

if/else and the ternary operator are compiled into the same basic opcodes internally (OP_COND_EXPR). The only difference is that because the code inside the if/else blocks form a new scope, there is extra startup and teardown at the beginning/end of each block.

But the performance difference is unlikely to be significant, and 99.9% of the time you should write the code in the way that maximises readability - for example, not using the ternary operator in void context.